# Viconics E117 / P117 replacement by Honeywell Lyric T5

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

I just moved into my old neighbourhood after being away for 15 years. We bought this old house (1957) and it seems that the heating/cooling system got changed through times (Oil to electric in 2001 then added a heatpump around 2015 ish).

The furnace is a Powermatic and the heatpump is a GoodMan.

I want to replace the current thermostat (Viconics E117/P117) by a Honeywell Lyric T5 and hopefully bypass the legacy Viconics control board.

My ultimate goal would be to have a more sensible thermostat that I can program and manage when I am out of town (i.e. start the air conditioning in advance when I am away for the weekend...). The Lyric T5 allows me to do that using Apple HomeKit technology (same as the rest of my home automation gadgets...)

This project seems doable. I saw this tread (dating from 3 years back) of a member that made the switch to a Nest.

[Installing Nest on Viconics P117 Board](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/149173/installing-nest-on-viconics-p117-board)

Here's my question :

**How do I wire this to make it work and bypass the Viconics entirely?**

I have included here the wiring plan for the current Viconics thermostat. I understand that this is a 2-part system. The control panel with the adjustment buttons ET117 and the actual brain P117. They communicate together via 3 wires (Red, Black, White). This drives the show for the rest. It allows the switch from heating from the heathpump to the furnace whenever it's too cold outside and it's not efficient to use the heatpump (around -13C ish). It shows "auxiliary" on the control panel at that moment.

[image]

I have done a representation of the actual wiring I have from the control panel to the furnace/heatpump. I do have wires (from legacy installations) still in the wall and somewhat still connected in a junction box accessible in the basement ceiling. All in all, only the red, white and black wires from the 18-5 are in use. I do have also a unused 3 wired (red, black, white) and unused 2 wires (black, white). Here's what it looks like.

[image]

I have done some research on the Honeywell UWP and came up with a first draft of what I think could make sense. I'am far from being an expert I must admit. I want to make sure I am keeping my family warm in this Canadien winter (average of -23C this week...). You can see in this picture the "future state" wiring schema. I am using all the existing wires from the control to the furnace/heatpump. I have also included a primary junction box because the amount of wire I have near the UWP is too short (2 inches..). I wanted to create some wiggle room.

[image]

Would this work? What should I change? Thank you SO much for your knowledge! (and sorry for the long message... I wanted to provide as much detail as possible...)

Comment: There is no direct messaging system on Stack Exchange. Additionally, that user was last logged into SE more than a year ago (click his user name to get details), and, with only 18 rep points, wasn't particularly active. If you have questions that the referenced question didn't answer, [edit] this question to actually ask them. Someone helped that user and someone will help you. Once you hit 50 rep, you can join in the chat room to ask questions broad questions like what you've asked here. Please do [edit] your question, even if it gets closed as being off topic.

Comment: Alex, just go ahead and ask your questions. Just like that other question was useful to you, your questions may be useful to someone else who comes along with a similar situation - that's the point of Stack Exchange. Try to only ask one 'main' question per 'question' though - it's preferred that you split complex topics over multiple questions.

Comment: Thank you for the tips "FreeMan and @brhans. I've edited my original question to add more details and a precise question. Let me know if you need actual picture of the installation.

Comment: @FreeMan should I "ask" a new question with the added content to get more attention? I feel it might have flew under the radar singe I edited it... Let me know!

Comment: Your edit popped the question to the top of the "recent activity" pile, so it should have been noticed by the people who have the knowledge to answer it. I certainly recall seeing it again after your edit. If it doesn't get attention, a bounty can be added to it (though not by you, you don't have enough rep to do so), this usually gets it more attention. I think the comments also pop it to the top of the "recent activity" pile, too.

Comment: "We’re you successful with this project? I have pretty much the same installation. Any update would be appreciated as I starting the same process (replacing this old system with a new thermostat (ecobee or nest)). I’m also in Quebec." -- Asked by user "Lacip" just a few hours ago...